# Call super method of super class from child class

Tags: flutter, dart, abstract-class

I have an abstract class A:

```
abstract class A {
    Future<String> firstMethod();
}
```

and I implemented this abstract class:

```
class Aimp implements A {
  @override
  Future<String> firstMethod() async {
      return "test";
  }
}
```

I have created another abstract class:

```
abstract class B extends A {
  
    Future<String> secondMethod();
}
```

and I implemented this abstract class:

```
class Bweb extends B {
    @override
      Future<Object> secondMethod() async {
          final t = //I want to call firstMethod()
         if(t.isNotEmpty()) // do sth
    }
}
```

In the implementation of secondMethod(), how can I call the implementation of firstMethod()?

I don't want to use **mixin**.

Comment: May I know why don't like to use mixin while using inheritance already ?

Comment: There is no particular reason, I want to use it like java @YeasinSheikh

Comment: try Moïse Rajesearison's post

Comment: I guess it works, it is mixin way

Comment: Not likely[I would say], it is already inherited from `A` on `B with Aimp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to use with instead:

```
abstract class A {
    Future<String> firstMethod();
}

class Aimp implements A {
  @override
  Future<String> firstMethod() async {
      return "test";
  }
}

abstract class B with Aimp {
    Future<String> secondMethod();
}

class Bweb extends B {
  
    @override
    Future<String> secondMethod() async {
         final String t = await firstMethod(); //Your firstMethod function
         if(t.isNotEmpty) {
           return t;
         }
      return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you need an object of Aimp class item as a field of Bweb class. Or place A class as a field for the B one.